# git branch issue

Tags: git

I have a local system where i work (windows) and commit changes and a production server (ubuntu) where i pull the changes.

I create a new branch when i have major changes on the code. Last branch is 0.9.1

I pull on the server with:

sudo git pull git@git.myrepo.com:myproject.git 0.9.1

however, i wanted to roll back to a previous branch (0.9) and can only see this when i do a branch -a:

```
* master
  remotes/origin/0.1
  remotes/origin/0.2
  remotes/origin/0.3
  remotes/origin/0.4
  remotes/origin/0.5
  remotes/origin/0.6
  remotes/origin/0.7
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
```

on my local machine i use git gui and I can see the branch 0.9 (and 0.8 and 0.9.1)
How come i cannot see it on the server?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should checkout a local branch try this instead of a git pull:

```
git checkout -b 0.9.1
```

After that, do your work then push the changes to the remote:

```
git push origin 0.9.1
```

Off topic, you should consider tags instead of branches for major releases.

Comment: yes, every branch has been pushed from my local machine, and pulled on the production server.

Comment: If that is the case, do a git pull and make sure your remote branches are up to date. If the results from git branch -a are the same then  you don't have a local or remote branch with that name.

Comment: i did a checkout -b and now i can see the branch there - thanks- , but why couldn't i see it before?

Comment: checkout -b creates a branch. If it let you do that then the branch didn't exist before. It created a branch off of the current branch that you were on previously and switched you to that branch. Based on the output you gave to git branch -r, there isn't a 0.9.1 on your computer or the remote server.